# Text divided to / distributed on multiple sheets

Tags: pdf

I would like to print a line with huge fonts that fits only 3 A4 landscape pages. I would like the text to be centered horizontally. Something like this:

```
|               |               |               |
| 1st  A4       | 2nd A4        |  3rd A4       |
|      This is a   line of  centered text.      |
|               |               |               |
```

I don't mind if I have to cut the edges of the paper sheets because of the printer margins.

How can I do this in latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way each page overlap a bit next page. If you want to see crops marks, use `crop=corners` or `crop=full`. If you have problems with printer margins, set a `imagewidth` and `imageheight` significatively smaller than `paperwidth` and `paperheight`.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{poster}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{160}{0}\selectfont
\poster[landscape=true,hcenter=true,vcenter=true,
crop=none]{This is a line of centered text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a lot nicer than my solution! I thought there should be a package that did this.

Comment: @Fran Where can I find the documentation of this poster package? I found a poster on CTAN but it is from 1999 and doesn't look like your example. Its manual only describes command line options.

Comment: This package is in TeXLive  only and the manual  is from 2010. I  see it running  `texdoc poster`, but in CTAN is available as [poster-mac](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/poster-mac). This is not the poster package  of Jos van Eijndhoven, tha t is only in MiKTEX.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like a slicker answer, but this will work.

Create one document to make the text on a large page. (Note that the 63cm equals 3 A4 pieces of paper.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth = 63cm, paperheight=29.7cm,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent=0in
\begin{document}
\centering%
\mbox{}\vfill%
\scalebox{6}{This is the most important announcement I have ever made}
\vfill%
\end{document}
```

Then make another document to include parts of first document. Change the scale below to work with your margins.  (Note that the viewport box is defined to split 63cm into thirds.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[clip,frame,viewport=0in 0in 21cm 27.9cm,scale=0.9]{test}
\includepdf[clip,frame,viewport=21cm 0in 42cm 27.9cm,scale=0.9]{test}
\includepdf[clip,frame,viewport=42cm 0in 63cm 27.9cm,scale=0.9]{test}
\end{document}
```

where `test` is the name of the first file's PDF.

Comment: I wanted to accept this solution too but the system doesn't allow. This solutions also works if the first pdf is generated by another program, not in latex.